# Display app icon on top of all window in android wear?

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-2.0

> I am developing an wear app, i want the app icon to be display on top of window
>   above the watch face. I have tried using WindowManager but failed to get the
>   result.
>
> WindowManager.LayoutParams params=new
>   WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
>                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
>                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
>                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
>                  PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
>
> ```
>    params.gravity= Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER;
>    params.x=160;
>    params.y=160;
>
>    windowManager=(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
>    windowManager.addView(mfloatview,params);
> ```
>
> my question is it possible to add an floating app icon in android wear?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this feature (Display app icon on top of all window) is available. But you can try checking the documentation - [Watch Face Complications](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/complications.html).

> A complication is any feature in a watch face that displays more than hours and minutes. For example, a battery indicator is a complication. The Complications API is for both watch faces and data provider apps.

Just like this:

[image]

Since you are using Android Wear 2.0, Complication API will be available for use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Rebot, i tried this one and it works for wear also... http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-chat-head/

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this one and works for android wear also... 
>   apply same concept to wear, it works 
>   http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-chat-head/